# ASP.NET Dynamic C# command

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, dynamic, command

> I want to make class for myself and I was writing this code and I hit the wall

```
public static string url(string example)
{
    string back = "";
    if(example == "random1")
    {
        back = "Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString()";
    }
    return back;
}
```

I want use my `Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString()` command in my asp net project example > default.aspx.cs >  `url("random1");`

> I had searched for a long time before , sorry about low in english :/

Comment: You just need to remove the double quotes from around Request.Url.Absolute.ToString()

Comment: [img](http://s32.postimg.org/g9h2b6kd1/Ads_z.jpg)
this problem

Comment: Do you have a using statement for System.Web? If you are in a class you may have to use the full path: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString()

Comment: thank you it is working , can i use this method for other C# commands ?

Comment: Yes, when needed. You just have to include the libraries you want to use with a using statement, in this case System.Web.

Comment: last question , can i use method like this ?
'CommandBehavior example = CommandBehavior)example_method;'

Comment: If you are referencing a function I would just use a Func<>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use something like this:

```
public static string url(string example)
{
    string back = "";
    if (example == "random1")
    {
        back = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString();
    }
    return back;
}
```

or even shorter:

```
public static string url(string example)
{
    return example == "random1" ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath : "";
}
```

Comment: thank you , if i want to build a dynamic method simply public static void example() like this bu i want to get method commands in a i dont know txt file maybe or like this what can i use ?

Comment: really can't understand what you're asking:/